# How to make Windows DLL for GameMaker Extension by Dlang?

Tags: windows, dll, d, game-maker, gml

I'm trying to make dll for gamemaker by dlang.

I used this video as reference.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jkgMxrDvwPs

This video shows how to make dll by c++.

```
#define GMEXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

GMEXPORT double cube(double n){
    return n*n*n;
}

GMEXPORT double aplusb(double a, double b){
    return a+b;
}
```

I tried to translate this code to dlang.

I used this article as refference.

https://wiki.dlang.org/Win32_DLLs_in_D#DLLs_with_a_C_Interface

```
import core.sys.windows.dll;
import core.sys.windows.windows;
import std.stdio;

__gshared HINSTANCE g_hInst;

extern (Windows)
BOOL DllMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, ULONG ulReason, LPVOID pvReserved)
{
    switch (ulReason)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        g_hInst = hInstance;
        dll_process_attach( hInstance, true );
        break;

    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        dll_process_detach( hInstance, true );
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        dll_thread_attach( true, true );
        break;

    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        dll_thread_detach( true, true );
        break;
    default:
        assert(false);
    }
    return true;
}


extern (C) {
    double cube(double n) {
        return n*n*n;
    }
    double aplusb(double a, double b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

And I built with dub with dmd(x86).

dub.json

```
{
    "name": "example",
    "targetType": "dynamicLibrary"
}
```

Then I tried to use this dll in gamemaker like the reference video.
But I got this error.

```
Error defining an external function.
 at gml_Object_object0_CreateEvent_1 (line 1) - dll_cube = external_define("example.dll", "cube", dll_cdecl, ty_real, 1, ty_real);
```

What do I do next?

Thank you.

Comment: You will have to wrap your head around [calling conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx).

Comment: Don't use `external_define` function, add it as extention instead.